# Find (and delete) all files with hard link count = 1

Tags: find, osx, rm, macintosh, hard-link

I'm having a tough time trying to reclaim some unused disk space on one of my macOS 10.13 partitions.

Thanks to [GrandPerspective](http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net), I think I found out that every time I delete some items in Photos for Mac, *in the case where they were inherited from iPhoto*, what happens is that the **hard link** sitting in the `Photo Library.photoslibrary` folder is deleted, so resulting in an orphaned file being left over in the `iPhoto Library.migratedphotolibrary` folder.

So what I would need is to

1. find all files with hard link count = 1 in the old `iPhoto Library.migratedphotolibrary` folder (the ones with link count = 2 need to stay there, as most likely they are hard-linked also in the new `Photo Library.photoslibrary` folder);
2. delete them.

Some batch procedure executable from Terminal achieving both on the fly would be super. Even some initial hint would help me out a lot.

Comment: I'm sure you know better about your situation than me, but if you deleted the files with link count 2 in the old folder as well, wouldn't they still remain as files with link count 1 in the new library folder, and isn't that what you want?

Comment: Guess you are right! Just did not think about it :)

Answer (score 1):

You are so close: You use `find` and `rm`.

```
 find «directory name» -links 1 -exec echo '{}' '+'
```

`echo` is not the correct command. After testing, change it to `rm --`.

Comment: Does MacOS' `find` have the `--delete` action? Saves a bit of possible headache with filename quoting.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Does it? There are no quoting issues with `-exec rm {} +` as far as I know, unless you're running `tcsh`.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz, it's `-delete`, and yes, Mac's `find` has it. Not that `-exec rm {} +` should have any quoting issues anyway (it doesn't run a shell)